# Github Action Docker Image of ASP.net Core application

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, github-actions

So I'm trying to build a docker image of an asp.net project that I created in Visual Studio with Docker enabled.

Now my understanding is that the .dockerignore file is in the solutions folder and the Dockerfile is in the project file, so I have to run my script from within the solution folder, and then tell it that the docker file is located at /Restraunts_API/Dockerfile for it to run correctly. (yes I know its spelt wrong)

I can't see why this isn't working

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./EcoBadge_Solution/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build --tag apirestaurant:$(date +%s) --file Restraunt_API/Dockerfile .
```

It is set to run in my solution folder and the Dockerfile is set as the one in the project folder. Why cant it find my .csproj file?

The github action errors with

```
Step 7/17 : COPY ["Restraunt_API/Restraunt_API.csproj", "Restraunt_API/"]
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat Restraunt_API/Restraunt_API.csproj: file does not exist
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

And the Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Restraunt_API/Restraunt_API.csproj", "Restraunt_API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Restraunt_API/Restraunt_API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Restraunt_API"
RUN dotnet build "Restraunt_API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Restraunt_API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Restraunt_API.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was that the `Dockerfile` was not in the correct location.

Please move the `Dockerfile` to the upper folder path, it will solve this problem. It means move the dockfile from the project directory to the solution directory.

Comment: Can't really do this if you have multiple projects in one solution